# Yosemite upgrading process quit and shows "File system verify or repair failed"

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I tried to install Yosemite, but I got an error: "File system verify or repair failed".

Now I want to get back to my Mavericks. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This probably means that the disk or the image from which you installed Yosemite was corrupt. It's time to restore your Mac from the backup you've created before installing Yosemite. (You did one, right?)

Connect your hard drive where the Time Machine backup is on, or make sure the network volume (e.g. Time Capsule) is online. Restart the Mac and hold the Command (⌘) and R keys.

Once the recovery menu appears, select "Restore from a Time Machine Backup".

Now follow the assistant and recover your system to the previous state.

Before re-installing Yosemite, make sure you [verify and repair any disk issues](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1782).

Comment: But why am I not able to boot Mavericks?

Comment: Did the installer run through or did it quit before that? You could also try [running Disk Utility from the recovery menu](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1417) and verify/repair from there.

Comment: No it did not run through. I am currently copying all data which are not in my latest backup to my external drive via terminal. I will try to boot in safe mode then.

Comment: "Belt & Braces" update method ... fix perms, verify/repair disk, run update, fix perms, verify/repair disk. All assumes current backup.

Comment: @slhck i do not have any backup and also no apple care . How can i install mac ox 10.10 . I am trying to repair disk permission but i need to be sure if that is right way . I am on my phone can you guide what option are left with no backup,

Comment: @Abhishek Repairing disk permissions is something you can always try. With no backup you could perhaps try to boot off a Linux live system from USB and then copy your important files, then erase the disk and install OS X again from recovery mode.

Comment: Thanks for the info, seems like it is not providing the option to repair permissions, seems like i will have to install linux